# best way to mimic docker's layer caching of a common base image with singularity?

Tags: singularity-container

I'm new to containerization, so apologies if I misuse some terminology.

I am providing data analysis software for a scientific collaboration with a rapid release cycle, meant to run on HPC clusters. It requires a large base image (lots of large packages) that would change much more slowly. Because it needs to run unprivileged on HPC clusters, singularity is the best-supported container solution.

The concern is the lack of layers with singularity.  If, say, my base image is 3 GB and my application software is 20 MB, there is a new 3.02 GB image for every single release. If docker were a viable solution, the layer mechanism would ensure that the base image is only downloaded once, and only the new application layer is retrieved on subsequent pulls. **Is there a good way with singularity to split my image into base and application "layers"?**

It seems like this must be a common setup, with a large, mostly-static common base image and a smaller, more-rapid application layer that would benefit from caching the base, but I can't find any description of how I might achieve this.

Comment: What's the end goal for the layers? Reduced build time, reduced image size, something else?

Comment: @tsnowlan Reduced disk usage for a set of images, where I have, say, 20 versions of my application software that could share a common base image (as would happen naturally with docker layers)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called "Image Mounts", and is supported starting with Singularity 3.6: https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#image-mounts .

From the documentation:

> In Singularity 3.6 and above you can mount a directory contained in an image file into a container. This may be useful if you want to distribute directories containing a large number of data files as a single image file.
>
> You can mount from image files in ext3 format, squashfs format, or SIF format.
>
> The ext3 image file format allows you to mount it into the container read/write and make changes, while the other formats are read-only.

Answer (score -1):

Singularity doesn't support that type of modularity, as it is more about having a standalone image that can create reproducible results regardless of where it is run. Docker can have this shared layer cache because it is a centralized service run on a machine that all users in the group share. When you export a Docker image, you also end up a single large(r) file.

If you are concerned about a large image archive, the usual tricks for minimizing Docker image sizes also apply for Singularity. If data is the main source of image size, you can package that separately and mount it into the image as needed.